# signal handler not working

Tags: c, pthreads, zeromq

I'm using `czmq` and `zmq` libraries in my code. I've registered a signal handler for `SIGINT` by calling `signal` in main. The code looks like this:

```
#include "czmq.h"

void sig_int(int signal);

void* pub_handler(){
    zctx_t *context = zctx_new ();
    void *publisher = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_PUB);

    zsocket_connect (publisher, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    sleep(1);

    char topic[20] = "REQ: speedlimit";

 // while (true)
    {
        sleep( randof(10) );
        zstr_sendm (publisher, topic);
        zstr_send (publisher, "driver analysis data");
    }
    zctx_destroy (&context);

}

void* sub_handler(){
    zctx_t *context = zctx_new();
    void *subscriber = zsocket_new (context, ZMQ_SUB);

    zsocket_connect (subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5557");

    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));

    char subscription [20] = "RESP: speedlimit" ;

    zsocket_set_subscribe (subscriber, subscription);

    while (true) {
        char *topic = zstr_recv (subscriber);
        if(!topic)
            break;
        char *data = zstr_recv (subscriber);
        assert (streq (topic, subscription));
        puts (topic);
        puts (data);
        free (topic);
        free (data);
    }
    zctx_destroy (&context);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t pub_id, sub_id;
    signal (SIGINT, sig_int);
    pthread_create(&pub_id, NULL, pub_handler, NULL);
    pthread_create(&sub_id, NULL, sub_handler, NULL);

    pthread_join(pub_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(sub_id, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void sig_int(int signal){
    printf (" Interrupted\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

compiled as `gcc -o app app.c -lpthread -lczmq -lzmq`.

The above code doesn't get into signal handler when `ctrl+c` interrupt is given.

what is the problem with `czmq` or `zmq` library and how it should be handled?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? If so, please accept an answer. Doing so will help others in future

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation for zctx](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zctx) says that `zctx` sets up its own signal handler for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`, probably overriding your signal handler.

> Sets up signal (SIGINT and SIGTERM) handling so that blocking calls
>   such as zmq_recv() and zmq_poll() will return when the user presses
>   Ctrl-C.

It also says that `zctx` is deprecated in favor of [`zsock`](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zsock), which doesn't appear to setup a signal handler according to its documentation. So my first suggestion is to use the new `zsock` socket API.

However, it seems that in both cases you can also call `zsys_handler_set(NULL);` (documented [here](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zsys)) to explicitly disable the default SIGINT/SIGTERM handling in CZMQ.

PS: `printf` is not async-signal-safe, meaning that it should not be used in a signal handler. See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03) for a list of async-signal-safe functions in POSIX.

Comment: yeah! I read that, zctx set's up it's own signal handler. But, my program doesn't terminate when ctrl+c is given(even without using any signal handler's).

Comment: If you have `while (true) {}` loops, of course it doesn't terminate. The zctx documentation says that only the `zmq_recv()` and `zmq_poll()` functions will return control to your code.

Comment: But, if I register the signal in any of the threads then it is working fine. I don't know what's happening!!

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution after posting the question in `zmq mailing list`!!

[Pieter Hintjens](https://github.com/hintjens) say's :: ***`CZMQ` does set up its own signal handling to trap SIGINT and SIGTERM.
You can disable this by calling***

```
zsys_handler_set (NULL);
```

Adding the above line in my code disabled the signal handler setup by czmq and now I can use my own signal handler.

Thanks to Pieter Hintjens.

Comment: Context from http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zctx

`The zctx class has these main features:
...
Sets up signal (SIGINT and SIGTERM) handling so that blocking calls such as zmq_recv() and zmq_poll() will return when the user presses Ctrl-C.
`

Answer (score 3):

> what is the problem ...

From [`man signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> The effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified.

Use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem has nothing to do with CZMQ as such, and is caused by your threading. Specifically, the main thread is catching the signal, and the child thread is not. This is a common trap.

There are several solutions. What I'd perhaps do is sleep/wait in the main thread (you can e.g. use zmq_poll) and then when you get the signal, tell the child threads to end.

Some comments... if you are going to use CZMQ, then why not use its threading facilities, which wrap pthreads in a nicer interface. You have the older zthread class, and the newer zactor class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main program should be alive. Try this-

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t pub_id, sub_id;
    signal (SIGINT, sig_int);
    pthread_create(&pub_id, NULL, pub_handler, NULL);
    pthread_create(&sub_id, NULL, sub_handler, NULL);

    pthread_join(pub_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(sub_id, NULL);

    while(1); // Fix
}
```

---

You have changed the signal table using `signal` function.

```
signal (SIGINT, sig_int);
```

So whenever you will give `SIGINT` signal(ctrl+c), it will call the `sig_int` function. That is your signal handler. But in that function you are not killing any process.

So whenever you press `ctrl + c`, your program just call's the `sig_int` function, That function will print `Interrupted` for every `SIGINT` signal.

If you need your program want's to terminate when you press `ctrl+c`, don't modify the signal table like below.

```
signal (SIGINT, sig_int);
```

Instead of that

```
signal (SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```

It will terminate your program, when you press `ctrl+c`.

Else you can try this also-

```
void sig_int(int signal){
signal (SIGINT, SIG_DFL); // here i am again changing the signal table to default.
printf (" Interrupted\n");
exit(0);
}
```

In this case, when you press `ctrl+c` first time it will call the `sig_int` function, but when you press second time it will terminate your program. because i have modified the signal table inside your `sig_int` function.

Comment: I tried those already! It doesn't even print `Interrupted`. `zctx` has some other way to handle signals that I couldn't figure out.